# MongoDB updating variable based on date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, time

I am trying to update a database field on a MongoDB collection using Meteor at an exact time -- say 12:00 AM every Monday.

How should I go about doing this?

I am trying matching the day of the week and the exact time number but I can't seem to make it work for the server to do this more than once without using a loop that will make the website freeze.

Comment: I think setting up a cron job could solve your problem. https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can install a cron-job npm module, like: `npm install cron`, than you could set up a cron job with a Monday-only pattert, to call your db update code.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 00 12 * * 1', function() {
  /*
   * Runs every weekday Monday at 12:00:00
   */
  }, function () {
    /* DB update code */
  }
);
```

Docs available at https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron, if you need to fine tune your cron pattern or other options.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was perfect. I actually ended up using https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/synced-cron since it worked with Meteor JS.